# exported and unexported in Go explanation

Tags: go

I skimmed through math package in Golang GitHub repo. Some of them have two difference function declarations. In the code below, [`sqrt.go`](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/math/sqrt.go) has `Sqrt` and `sqrt` func. My questions are: 
Why do they implement it this way? What are the benefits? Is this because of the exported and unexported identifier (lowercase vs uppercase first letter)?

```
func Sqrt(x float64) float64

// Note: Sqrt is implemented in assembly on some systems.
// Others have assembly stubs that jump to func sqrt below.
// On systems where Sqrt is a single instruction, the compiler
// may turn a direct call into a direct use of that instruction instead.

func sqrt(x float64) float64 {
```

`math.Sqrt()`

Comment: The comment you quoted is pretty much the answer to your question. What is unclear with this comment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Function_declarations), function declarations without a body, as you show in the [first line of the code you quoted](https://golang.org/src/math/sqrt.go?s=3704:3732#L82), provide a declaration for code implemented outside of Go; usually in assembly or another language.

In this case, most implementations for that `func Sqrt(x float64) float64` are in assembly; for example [386](https://golang.org/src/math/sqrt_386.s?s=183:243), [amd64](https://golang.org/src/math/sqrt_amd64.s?s=184:243), [arm](https://golang.org/src/math/sqrt_arm.s?s=184:243), etc.

Sample from amd64:

```
// func Sqrt(x float64) float64
TEXT ·Sqrt(SB),NOSPLIT,$0
    SQRTSD x+0(FP), X0
    MOVSD X0, ret+8(FP)
    RET
```

For architectures that have no assembly implementation the assembly simply refers to the unexported / private `func sqrt(x float64) float64` version that is in Go.  For example the [mips64](https://golang.org/src/math/stubs_mips64x.s?s=1370:1413#L87) architecture.

```
TEXT ·Sqrt(SB),NOSPLIT,$0
    JMP ·sqrt(SB)
```